# Changing the colour of the text with itemize

Tags: beamer, color, itemize

I'm creating my own `beamer` theme. I can change the colour of the bullets using `\setbeamercolor{}`. But how can I change the colour of the text after the bullets? I would like to use it in a `.sty` file.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\definecolor{INBObrown}{RGB}{118, 91, 52}
\definecolor{INBOreddishbrown}{RGB}{182, 101, 70}
\definecolor{INBOblue}{RGB}{86, 152, 200}
\setbeamercolor{item}{fg=INBObrown}
\setbeamercolor{subitem}{fg=INBOreddishbrown}
\setbeamercolor{subsubitem}{fg=INBOblue}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item This text should be in colour INBObrown
    \begin{itemize}
      \item This text should be in colour INBOreddishbrown
      \begin{itemize}
        \item This text should be in colour INBOblue
      \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

The following should work:

```
\setbeamercolor{itemize/enumerate body}{fg=INBObrown}
\setbeamercolor{itemize/enumerate subbody}{fg=INBOreddishbrown}
\setbeamercolor{itemize/enumerate subsubbody}{fg=INBOblue}
```

**Edit**: Just found a previously [existing answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/126627/2151).

Comment: This is the correct solution without hacking around!

Answer (score 5):

The following works:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer

\definecolor{INBObrown}{RGB}{118, 91, 52}
\definecolor{INBOreddishbrown}{RGB}{182, 101, 70}
\definecolor{INBOblue}{RGB}{86, 152, 200}
\setbeamercolor{item}{fg=INBObrown}
\setbeamercolor{subitem}{fg=INBOreddishbrown}
\setbeamercolor{subsubitem}{fg=INBOblue}

\makeatletter
\def\beamer@origitem{%
  \@inmatherr\item\@ifnextchar[\@item{\@noitemargtrue\@item[\@itemlabel]%
  \csname beamer@thcfg@\beameritemnestingprefix item\endcsname% Insert colour in \beamer@thc@fg
  \ifx\beamer@thc@fg\@empty\relax\else\color{\beamer@thc@fg}\fi% Execute colour
  }}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item This text should be in colour INBObrown
    \begin{itemize}
      \item This text should be in colour INBOreddishbrown
      \begin{itemize}
        \item This text should be in colour INBOblue
      \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The idea is to capture the current item (foreground) colour in a macro called `\beamer@thc@fg` by executing the associated key-value macro. Then, simply applying that colour after setting the item label.

Comment: Your solution works great if I put the \makeatletter stuff in the tex file itself. However, I would like to put that in a theme (.sty file). And then it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Just had a similar problem and used a more succinct solution

```
\let\olditem\item
\renewcommand{\item}{\olditem  \color{INBObrown}}
```

the same for lower levels.

Comment: nest your itemize lists and you'll see why it isn't enough