# Change item and subitem text colour in beamer lists

Tags: beamer, formatting, lists, color

I am using `Montpellier` theme for `beamer` presentation. I need to change the item and subitem text colors. I also need to make the subitem text italics. How do I do that?

Comment: Are you talking about items in an `enumerate`, `itemize` or `description` environment?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Yes I am talking about enumerate and itemize only. Not the text inside bullets but the actual content after the bullets. Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the best way is to redefine the color for the template `itemize/enumerate body` and the font for the template `itemize/enumerate subbody`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Montpellier}

\setbeamercolor{itemize/enumerate body}{fg=green}
\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate subbody}{shape=\itshape}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Test}
  \begin{itemize}
     \item First item
     \item Second item
       \begin{itemize}
         \item First subitem
         \item Second subitem
       \end{itemize}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thanks for the appreciation!

Comment: I am sorry to say that I am getting the following error:
! File ended while scanning use of \beamer@collect@@body.
:(

Comment: @cosmicraga If you don't provide a MWE that reproduces the error I can't say more.

Comment: Working. Great.