# Itemized text does not follow the tcbset color

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, luatex

This is my `mwe` for my beamer. As you can see, in the `hlcard` environment, the normal text changes its color, but not the `itemized environment`.

```
\documentclass[8pt,xcolor=dvipsnames,xcolor=table, handout]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
\usepackage[customcolors,shade]{hf-tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shadows,petri,decorations.markings,shapes}
\RequirePackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{mathtools}\definecolor{dcol}{named}{Maroon}
    \tcbset{%
        left=6mm, right=6mm, top=6mm, bottom=6mm, middle=4mm,
    }

    \tcbset{%
        outerlayer/.style={%
                enhanced,
                sharpish corners=all,
                colbacktitle=dcol,
                coltitle=white, coltext=dcol,
                left=1mm,
                right=1mm,
                top=1mm,
                bottom=1mm,
                middle=4mm,
                toptitle=1mm,
                bottomtitle=1mm,
                fuzzy shadow={0mm}{0.9mm}{0.6mm}{0.2mm}{black!20!Grey}, % top
                fuzzy shadow={0mm}{-0.6mm}{-0.1mm}{0.2mm}{black!40!Grey}, % bottomSmall
                fuzzy shadow={0mm}{-0.2mm}{-0.2mm}{0.2mm}{black!20!Grey}, % bottomBig
                title filled, boxrule=0mm, %
                segmentation code={\path[draw=BGrey](segmentation.west) -- (segmentation.east);}
            },
        innerlayer/.style={outerlayer,
                noparskip,
                breakable,
                colback=dcol,%
                coltitle=black,
                coltext=White,
                fonttitle={\bfseries \scshape},
                bottomtitle=1mm}
    }

    \newtcolorbox{card}[1][]{%
        outerlayer,
        title=#1,
    }

    \newtcolorbox{hlcard}[1][]{%
        innerlayer,
        colback=Teal,
        box align=base,
        #1
    }

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
    \begin{hlcard}[]
        Hello from normal text
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Hello from itemized text
        \end{itemize}
    \end{hlcard}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

What I am doing wrong here?

[image]

Comment: Do you want to change the itemize textcolor only inside the `hlcard`-environment or globally?

Comment: off-topic: your MWE doesn't work. for color names you need option `svgnames` ...

Comment: `beamer` always sets the `itemize` item color with its own mechanisms. This has nothing to do with `tcolorbox`. You can change it with `\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=<color>}`.

Comment: @TimHilt: I just want to change it inside `hlcard`.

Comment: You could add `code={\setbeamercolor*{normal text}{fg=white}\usebeamercolor{normal text}},` to your hlcard options.

Answer (score 1):

As a followup to Werners answer in [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84958/changing-the-colour-of-the-text-with-itemize), i would recommend you to change the color to a custom color (white in the MWE) at the begin of the colorbox and back to `normal color` at the end.

---

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[8pt,xcolor=dvipsnames,xcolor=table, xcolor=svgnames, handout]{beamer}
% \mode<presentation>

\usepackage[customcolors,shade]{hf-tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shadows,petri,decorations.markings,shapes}
\RequirePackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{mathtools}\definecolor{dcol}{named}{Maroon}

\tcbset{%
  left=6mm, right=6mm, top=6mm, bottom=6mm, middle=4mm,
}

\tcbset{%
  outerlayer/.style={%
    enhanced,
    sharpish corners=all,
    colbacktitle=dcol,
    coltitle=white, coltext=dcol,
    left=1mm,
    right=1mm,
    top=1mm,
    bottom=1mm,
    middle=4mm,
    toptitle=1mm,
    bottomtitle=1mm,
    fuzzy shadow={0mm}{0.9mm}{0.6mm}{0.2mm}{black!20!Grey}, % top
    fuzzy shadow={0mm}{-0.6mm}{-0.1mm}{0.2mm}{black!40!Grey}, % bottomSmall
    fuzzy shadow={0mm}{-0.2mm}{-0.2mm}{0.2mm}{black!20!Grey}, % bottomBig
    title filled, boxrule=0mm, %
    segmentation code={\path[draw=BGrey](segmentation.west) -- (segmentation.east);}
  },
  innerlayer/.style={outerlayer,
    noparskip,
    breakable,
    colback=dcol,%
    coltitle=black,
    coltext=White,
    fonttitle={\bfseries \scshape},
    bottomtitle=1mm}
}

\newtcolorbox{card}[1][]{%
  outerlayer,
  title=#1,
}

\newtcolorbox{hlcard}[1][]{%
  innerlayer,
  colback=Teal,
  box align=base,
  before upper={\setbeamercolor{item}{fg=white}},
  after upper={\setbeamercolor{item}{fg=normal color}}
  #1
}

\makeatletter
\def\beamer@origitem{%
  \@inmatherr\item\@ifnextchar[\@item{\@noitemargtrue\@item[\@itemlabel]%
  \csname beamer@thcfg@\beameritemnestingprefix item\endcsname% Insert colour in \beamer@thc@fg
  \ifx\beamer@thc@fg\@empty\relax\else\color{\beamer@thc@fg}\fi% Execute colour
  }}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}
  \begin{hlcard}[]
    Text inside hlcard
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Itemize Text
    \end{itemize}
  \end{hlcard}

  Text outside hlcard

  \begin{itemize}
  \item Normal itemize text
  \item Foo
  \item Bar
  \item Baz
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]